# Matplotlib same LaTeX format for text and float-to-string part

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, latex, legend

I am trying to work on the legend of my graph:

[image]

As you can see that I used the dollar symbol for **timestep** to make it latex (I hope I am not wrong) but I am unable to get the same font/format for the time value which I have converted from float to string.

Part of my code

```
...
while i < len(files):
....
time = '$timestep\ $'+ str(float(start))
lns1 = ax.plot(x,y,label=time,linewidth=3)
...
```

Comment: Please do not provide your code in screenshots, but copy the part of the code you want help with in your question.

Comment: Made the change, many thanks.

Comment: putting text inside `$` is just formatting it as math text. To render everything in latex, you can set the `rcParam` called 'text.usetex'  to `True`. See here: https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/tutorials/text/usetex.html